# Invalid SQL WHERE clause using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I do a where clause in SQL Server? I keep running into very odd errors. For example, this works:

```
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SalesRawData WHERE title IS NULL')
```

But this errors:

```
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SalesRawData WHERE title="asdf"')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 464, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7491)
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (207, "Invalid column name 'asdf'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: 
Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

I don't understand the error because I'm specifying the column is `title` and the value should be "asdf", but it seems to think I'm setting the column as asdf? What's going on here?

**Update**: it seems like this is the only way to get it to work:

```
SELECT * FROM SalesRawData WHERE Title = N'asdf'
```

Any idea why I have to add the `N` at the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your WHERE clause in the right place, but SQL Server uses single quotes, rather than double quotes, to specify string values. Double quotes are used to designate table or column names, which is why SQL is looking for a column named `asdf` rather than treating it as a value. The correct SQL would be `SELECT * FROM SalesRawData WHERE title='asdf'`.